# Pandas: backfilling missig Data and keeping the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, missing-data, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with many missing value the time interval is 5min, however, there are many missing timestamp as well.
Dataframe look like this:

```
Time                   A
2000-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2015-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2015-12-01 00:00:00   NaN
2015-12-01 12:40:00   NaN
2015-12-01 12:45:00   NaN


df.dropna().head(6)

Time                    A
2015-12-04 11:50:00    1.0
2016-04-11 16:15:00    1.0
2016-04-11 16:25:00    1.0
2016-04-29 22:05:00    1.0
2016-07-01 14:25:00    1.0
2016-07-23 21:20:00    1.0
```

I want to back fill the missing values for 10 days without changing the index. I used this command but there is no change in the results.

```
#fill the missing data
df_filled=df.groupby(df.index).fillna(method='bfill', limit=12*240)

df_filled.dropna().head(6)

Time                    A
2015-12-04 11:50:00    1.0
2016-04-11 16:15:00    1.0
2016-04-11 16:25:00    1.0
2016-04-29 22:05:00    1.0
2016-07-01 14:25:00    1.0
2016-07-23 21:20:00    1.0
```

I appreciate if any one can guide me.

Thanks in advance.

## Update:

a snapshot of one the values from df:

```
12/4/2015 11:15 NaN
12/4/2015 11:20 NaN
12/4/2015 11:25 NaN
12/4/2015 11:30 NaN
12/4/2015 11:35 NaN
12/4/2015 11:40 NaN
12/4/2015 11:45 NaN
12/4/2015 11:50 1
```

What I want to backfill data up to 10 days so for the same data point it should be:

```
12/4/2015 11:15 1
12/4/2015 11:20 1
12/4/2015 11:25 1
12/4/2015 11:30 1
12/4/2015 11:35 1
12/4/2015 11:40 1
12/4/2015 11:45 1
12/4/2015 11:50 1
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? Look at the dates in your index.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks,  The index up to 10 days does exist for some of those dates . so for example if I look up to 10 days before 12/4/2015 I can see that there are  68 data point with nan value. I want all these dates backfilled.

Comment: Maybe you want `df.resample('10D').bfill(limit=10)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  I update the question to clarify. when I use `df.resample('10D').bfill(limit=10) ` I get an empty data frame.

Comment: I also tested  `df_filled=df.asfreq(freq='10D').fillna(method='bfill', limit=1).dropna(how='all').drop_duplicates(keep='last')` but still get an empty dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works:

```
df_filled=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10D')).fillna(method='bfill')
```